# Convergence of $(f_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an uniformly continuous function. Suppose $f_n(x)=f\left(x+\cfrac{1}{n}\right)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. How can I prove that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a continuous function?

I just need some hint to begin please. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you tried proving that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.
Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon,$$
whenever $|x - y| < \delta.$

Now choose $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $1/N < \delta$. Then, for all $n \ge N$, we have
$$\left|f\left(x + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)\right| < \epsilon$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Using the defintion $f_n$, we get that
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon,$$
for all $n \ge N$ and $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: How did you prove that: $$\left|f\left(x + \dfrac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)\right| < \epsilon$$ that's where I'm sturggling

Comment: @clark979m That is just uniform continuity of $f.$ You have $|x+\frac{1}{n}-x|=\frac{1}{n}<\delta$ for all $n \geq N.$

Comment: Put $y = x + 1/n$ in the previous line and note that the inequality $|x - y| < \delta$ holds. (Why?)

Comment: right, but why proving that fn----->f solves the original question? we need to prove that fn converges uniformly but you proved only that it converges to f which is different

Comment: I feel like you're not aware of the definition. I have shown that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ **for all** $x \in \Bbb R$ and $n \ge N$.

Comment: the definition doesn't say that, do you have a link to review it again?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition). It seems from your duplicate post that you wish to show that $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon$. It shouldn't be hard for you to show that my condition implies yours.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|f\left(x+\frac1n\right)-f(x)\right|.$$ Now use uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: @clark979m In these kind of problems, it usually helps to write down what do you need to prove, and what do you have. Basically, you want to bound the quantity on the LHS in some sense, and you can get a bound for the RHS from the uniform continuity.

Comment: @clark979m I did not change OP's question to another...

Comment: ok but how to continue from here? to use uniform continuity of . we need x1 and x2 plus when need to prove that |fn(x1)-fn(x2)|<epsilon

Comment: @clark979m **Hint:** When you apply uniform continuity, corresponding to $\epsilon >0,$ you obtain $\delta>0.$ Choose $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0>\frac{1}{\delta}.$

Comment: I know that but again the doesn't answer my question, how will you continue from here? we don't know anything else that could be helpful without using f(x1) - f(x2)

Comment: @SahibaArora could you elaborate

Comment: @clark979m So for $n \geq n_0,$ you obtain $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ This proves uniform convergence.

Comment: but how to prove that |fn(x)-f(x)|<epsilon, that's my question

Comment: Clark: Sahiba Arora has been giving a very detailed explanation of how to show uniform convergence in this case. It's also clear from your comments that you don't fully understand the definition of uniform convergence (as also evidenced by your more recent post about the same problem, where you mis-state what it would mean for $f_n$ to converge uniformly to $f$). Please review the definition of uniform convergence from your textbook/other learning resource! Importantly, uniform convergence is a condition with many quantifiers, roughly ∀ε ∃N ∀n ∀x (...).