# prove that a sequence of functions is uniformly convergent

Tags: calculus, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

How to prove that for $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ a continuous function, and $(f_n)$ a sequence of functions such that

$$f_n(x) = f(x + 1/n), \forall n \in \mathbb N$$
converges uniformly in every interval $[a,b]$.

**Note:** I'm looking for ideas on which law or theory to use and not for full solution.

**Until now**, I have tried to prove that with the definition of uniform convergence using epsilon but that doesn't work here.

**Edit:**

I need to prove that for every epsilon>0 There in N so that for every n,m>N:$$|fn(x)-fm(x)| < epsilon$$

But from what I'm given that seems impossible to be proven

Comment: [This question was just asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685554/convergence-of-f-n/3685561#3685561)

Comment: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a-1,b+1]$.

Comment: But still that didn't help after I read it, it just says to use uniform continuity of .

Comment: Hey I don’t really think this should’ve been downvoted. I know you’ve tried to prove the result but can you type up everything you’ve tried so far?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats I have edited my question